# RotationTFToEigen no member of tf

Tags: ros-hydro, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

i have some code, which has been written for fuerte and is also compilable under fuerte.  I have to make it runable under hydro. When i compile one of the packages with rosmake, i get the following error:

```
error: ‘RotationTFToEigen’ is not a member of ‘tf’
error: ‘VectorTFToEigen’ is not a member of ‘tf’
```

To which namespace does these two now belong? Because in the api it looks like they should be members of tf.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171981/rotationtftoeigen-no-member-of-tf/) by [mr42](https://answers.ros.org/users/18686/mr42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would appear these functions were slightly renamed:

- You'll need to include "tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h"
- tf::RotationTFToEigen is renamed to tf::quaternionTFToEigen
- tf::VectorTFToEigen is now tf::vectorTFToEigen.

Docs for this header are here: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/tf_conversions/html/c++/tf__eigen_8h.html

This I believe was part of the overhaul that was done to get rid of the custom version of bullet that was used.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1